# probability of frog moving exactly 6 meters away

Tags: probability

A confused frog has lost its way. Every 10 seconds it decides where to turn to. With probability $\frac{1}{3} $ it jumps one meter to the right, with probability $\frac{1} {3}$it jumps on meter to the left, otherwise it says in its place. Assume that all decisions are mutually independent. Find the probability that after 1 minute and 40 seconds the frog will be at the distance of exactly 6 meters from its initial location.

The way I approach this problem is that I see in the time there can be 10 jumps, and to be 6 meters to one direction, there are 6 possibilities, either 2 jumps to the left and 8 to the right, 1 to the left, 2 pauses and 7 to the right, or 4 pauses and 6 to the left. All of this can be for the opposite directions as well. With each jump being a 1/3 probability, of going in a certain direction the total probability of being exactly 6 meters away would be

$$ (6) \times \left( \frac{1}{3}\right)^{\!10} $$

Is this right?

Comment: I suggest you check this logic on a much smaller problem where you can write out all the possible sequences of jumps and count the ones that succeed. Perhaps four jumps with a goal of landing two meters away.

Answer (score 1):

That is close, but you have to account for the number of ways each of those different possibilities can occur. Two jumps to the left and eight to the right can occur in ${10\choose{2}} = 45$ ways. 4 pauses and 6 to the left can happen in ${10\choose{4}} = 210$ ways. For 1 to the right, 2 pauses and 7 to the left, there are ${10\choose{3}}$ ways to order the left jumps, and then ${3\choose{2}}$ ways to order the other three jumps, giving ${10\choose{3}}{3\choose{2}} = 360$ ways. So there are 615 ways to end up 6 meters to the left and thus 1230 ways to end up 6 meters away. So the answer is $1230\times(\frac13)^{10}$

Answer (score 0):

It's not right.

Guide:

You forgot to take order of action into considerations. For example, if we know that there are $2$ jumps to the left and $8$ to the right. We will have to decide when to make the left jump and when to make the right jump. There are $\binom{10}2$ such choices.

Take order of actions into consideration for the other possibilities as well.